# What is the experimental design?

Tags: experiment-design

Besides RCT vs non RCT, versus prospective retrospective case control, dosage calculation, exclusion criteria, power analysis, sample size determination, and determining measurement time points and knowing what data to collect, what is involved in the experimental design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that there is no formal definition of experimental design. You have as many possible experimental designs as you have experiments. The list you provided is quite exhaustive, but many of these elements will be irrelevant for simple experiments. Conversely, if you perform sequential experiment design (i.e. if the design of experiment $t$ depends on the results of experiment $t-1$), you may have to consider $N$ times each of the elements you mentioned ($N$ being the number of experiments you wish to perform, which is itself also an experimental parameter). You may also consider that the models you used and the priors of their parameters are part of the experimental design.

You may want to have a look at the literature on [Optimal Experiment Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_experimental_design) for same examples, and especially on the following papers:

Emery, A. F., & Nenarokomov, A. V. (1998). Optimal experiment design. Measurement Science and Technology, 9(6), 864.

Huan, X., & Marzouk, Y. M. (2013). Simulation-based optimal Bayesian experimental design for nonlinear systems. Journal of Computational Physics, 232(1), 288-317.

Stephan, Klaas Enno, et al. "Ten simple rules for dynamic causal modeling." Neuroimage 49.4 (2010): 3099-3109.

Comment: I heard that payPhD people to design experiments. What’s so sophisticated and arcane about it that makes it require difficult knowledge that only Stephen Hawking people can grasp?

Comment: What are the technical details or knowledge prerequisites  that make it sophisticated?

Comment: Do I have to understand knot theory to do it? Or what insanely hard prereqsuite knowledge does it require?

Comment: I think you answered those questions also.